# Executing different methods based on a column value

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project, I have multiple methods with different codes to run.
Is it possible to execute the corresponding method based on the code number retrieved from another code?

I'm Executing the methods in the `static void Main` as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        string Query_void ="Select Void from Table_of_voids where Code = " +Result_Code+";";
        Do_something1();
    }
}
```

my idea is to be something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        string Query_void ="Select Void from Table_of_voids where Code = " +Result_Code+";";
        Query_void();
    }
}
```

this is the table of Method and Codes.

| Code | Method |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Do_something1 |
| 2 | Do_something2 |

I will have a lot of different arguments that will result in a different method. I know that I can do it by if statement but I'm wondering if there's any other option to save me time.

Comment: I edited your post and changed void to method. What you call "[void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/void)" is a [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/methods). Void is just a special type that tells you that you don't have to expect a return value from the method.

Comment: On a sidenote: Please use [query parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) instead of string concatenation. You open yourself up to SQL injection.

Comment: BTW: The code in the question doesn't make too much sense. Where does `Result_Code` come from? Where's your DB stuff? As is, you only have an unused string and a method call in a loop.

Comment: @Fildor thank you for your comments, Result_Code comes from if statements that reads Emails and determine if an email has some certain words, then the corresponding code of that word will be Result_Code , I have a dictionary of words already and based on the email content a code will be the result. I removed the DB connectionstring because it's not relevant to my question.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the connection string. You removed _anything_ in regards to DB apart from your query string. Which makes it hard to tell if there are other issues as well. Also: Do the methods you want to call need arguments? If so, all the same? Different ones? Where do _they_ come from if so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dictionary of Action with a string key like this:

Define the methods:

```
public static void BasicReaderQuery_1()
{

}
```

Init the dictionary:

```
    Dictionary<string, Action> dict = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
    dict.Add("query1", BasicReaderQuery_1);
```

Call the method with the key:

```
public static void run(string query) 
{
    dict[query]();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use reflection.

For example:

```
class TestClass
{
    public void Proc1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Proc1");
    }

    public void Proc2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Proc2");
    }

    public void CallProc(string procName)
    {
        var type = typeof(TestClass);

        var method = type.GetMethod(procName);
        method.Invoke(this, null);
    }
}
```

And the calling code is the following:

```
TestClass tc = new TestClass();
tc.CallProc("Proc1");
tc.CallProc("Proc2");
```